# How do I create a Lithium - form->select from controller output

Tags: forms, mongodb, lithium

I want to create a dropdown for types collection from MongoDB, in my MongoDB collection:

section has types and controller code with view code. I want to create a `form->select` from the output of the controller.

```
    types
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("5082c6109d5d0c640c000000"),
      "name": "JACKET CLUSTER FRONT"
    }
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("5082c62b9d5d0c440c00006e"),
      "name": "JACKET CLUSTER FRONT"
    }
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("5082c62b9d5d0c440c00006f"),
      "name": "TITLE WITHOUT SYMBOL"
    }
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("5082c62b9d5d0c440c000070"),
      "name": "FRONTISPIECE"
    }
*/

// in my controller
// -----------
    $types = Types::all(array('order'=>'_id'));
    $vtype = array($types)
    return compact('vtypes');

// in my view
// ------------------
    echo $this->form->select('types',$vtypes);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`find('list')` returns a key/value array, useful for any use where you would want a list such as for populating input select boxes.

```
$types = Types::find('list')

//returns
Array
(
[5082c6109d5d0c640c000000] => 'JACKET CLUSTER FRONT',
[5082c62b9d5d0c440c00006e] => 'JACKET CLUSTER FRONT',
[5082c62b9d5d0c440c00006f] => 'TITLE WITHOUT SYMBOL',
...
)
```

This finder looks for `$_meta['title']` of your model, which is by default `name` if this field is available, and `$_meta['key']` for the `id`, which should be `_id` in your case if your schema is correct

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I used this to achieve the result.

```
Types::meta('key', '_id');
Types::meta('title', 'filename');

$types = Types::find('list',array(
'fields'=>array('id','filename'),
'order'=>'id'));
```

Comment: Pls RTFM! find('list') doesn't need all that jazz to return a key/value pairs for populating a form select... Moreover, what you wrote is exactly what I explained in my answer